# How to use regex capture group inside a .nanorc file?

Tags: regex, bash, syntax-highlighting, nano

### How do I use a regex capture group inside a .nanorc file in combination with the `color` option?

The [Nanorc docs](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.1/nanorc.5.html) describe a color option, used to create syntax highlighting.

**color fgcolor,bgcolor regex**

*For the currently defined syntax, display all expressions matching the extended regular expression regex with foreground color fgcolor and background color bgcolor, at least one of which must be specified...*

Using the following regular expression would, if it is possible to use the capture group, allow me to fix an annoying bug inside the nano.bashrc syntax highlighting file which incorrectly highlights comments as follows:

[image]

The new (working) regex would be this:

```
{[^}]*}|\[[^\]]*\]|(#.*$)
```

It matches all content between (and including) curly braces, or all content between (and including) square brackets, and finally the `#` symbol followed by any character any amount of times until the end of the line. Still working on how to not match # if it's preceded by a dollar sign.

You can see a working demo of it here: https://regexr.com/3tdqf

I'd like to be able to highlight only actual comments, by using the first capture group as the filter for color highlighting!

Is it possible?

EDIT: I noticed that it is possible to provide a start pattern and end pattern for color highlighting, as per the docs:

**color fgcolor,bgcolor start="sr" end="er"**

*Display expressions which start with the extended regular expression sr and end with the extended regular expression er with foreground color fgcolor and background color bgcolor, at least one of which must be specified. This allows syntax highlighting to span multiple lines. Note that all subsequent instances of sr after an initial sr is found will be highlighted until the first instance of er.*

Perhaps this could help solve our dilemma :S

Comment: Try `{[^}]*}|\[.*\]|(?<!\$)(#.*$)` [here](https://regex101.com/r/3cWzJ3/1/).

Comment: That's lovely but negative look ahead/behind is not available in bash - just ERE (not PCRE). But I appreciate the input! I think what I need to figure out is how to somehow take the above regex and make it positively only match the `#` symbol, and all tokens after it up until line end, if it is not part of a code block, variable, etc -- so somehow "match # and succeeding chars up until end of sentence only if # is not inside curly braces, brackets, or preceeded by a dollar sign"

Comment: Updated regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/3cWzJ3/3/) which also catches `#` inside curved brackets: `()`

Comment: Try `{[^}]*}|\[.*\]|\([^\)]*\)|(?:\s|^)(#.*$)` [here](https://regex101.com/r/3cWzJ3/4).

Comment: Somewhat embarrassingly.... the bug I've been trying to fix is not a bug. From the screen shot - that's badly formatted bash (test conditions should look like `[ ! -z someThing ] && [ otherCondition ]` - fixing that provided proper code highlighting. Still, would be cool to know if this is possible anyhow

Comment: Did my regex not work for you?

Comment: The RegEx you provided works great - but it does not answer the OP about how to use the capture group as the filter for colour highlighting inside the .nanorc file (i.e. how to highlight only matches from the capture group and no other matches)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this question because I was looking how to use Nano to highlight functions in C. As mentioned in the above comments Nano uses POSIX extended regular expressions (ERE), and ERE does not have lookahead or lookbehind. The workaround relies on the fact that nanorc color syntax rules get applied in order, from top to bottom. We create rules that capture the entire group and then farther down; we create rules that change the colors of the characters we did not want.

```
## Comment
color green "#[#a-zA-Z0-9[:blank:]]*"
## Quoted text
color yellow "\"[^\"]*\""
## Allow commenting out a line of code
color green "^[[:blank:]]*#.*$"
## Braces
color blue "\{.*\}"
## Brackets
color blue "\[.*\]"
```

The code above matches the examples given by @GrayedFox [here](https://regexr.com/3tdqf) and @UnbearableLightness [here](https://regex101.com/r/3cWzJ3/4).